# boost serialization fails on cyclic restore

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I try to implement a serializer for two classes `Geometry` and `Dimension` that have a cyclic dependency between them. That means `Geometry` can have a `Dimension` and a `Dimension` knows its `Geometry`. Also, I have `DataModel` which contains a vector of geometries and dimensions. My classes look like this:

```
class IGeometry
{
public:
    virtual ~IGeometry() = default;
};

class IDimension
{
public:
    virtual ~IDimension() = default;
    virtual const std::vector<IGeometry*>& GetGeometries() const = 0;
};

class Dimension : public virtual IDimension
{
public:
    Dimension(std::vector<IGeometry*> f) : geometries{ std::move(f) } {}
    ~Dimension() override = default;

    const std::vector<IGeometry*>& GetGeometries() const override 
    {
        return geometries;
    }

private:
    std::vector<IGeometry*> geometries;
};

class Geometry : public virtual IGeometry
{
public:
    ~Geometry() override {}

    void AddDimension(IDimension* dimension)
    {
        dimensions.emplace_back(dimension);
    }
    const std::vector<IDimension*>& GetDimensions() const { return dimensions; }
private:
    std::vector<IDimension*> dimensions{};
};

struct DataModel
{
    std::vector<IGeometry*> geometries;
    std::vector<IDimension*> dimensions;
};
```

I am using non-intrusive serialization from boost like this:

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(Geometry)

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Dimension)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Geometry)

namespace boost
{
namespace serialization
{

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, IGeometry& g, const unsigned int version){ }

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, IDimension& d, const unsigned int version){ }

template<class Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const Geometry& g, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& boost::serialization::base_object<IGeometry>(g);
    ar& g.GetDimensions();
}
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, Geometry& g, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& boost::serialization::base_object<IGeometry>(g);

    std::vector<IDimension*> dimensions;
    ar& dimensions;
    for(auto* dimension : dimensions)
    {
        g.AddDimension(dimension);
    }
}

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, Dimension& d, unsigned int version)
{
    ar& boost::serialization::base_object<IDimension>(d);
}

template<class Archive>
void save_construct_data(Archive& ar, const Dimension* t, const unsigned int)
{
    ar& t->GetGeometries();
}

template<class Archive>
void load_construct_data(Archive& ar, Dimension* t, const unsigned int file_version)
{
    std::vector<IGeometry*> foos;
    ar& foos;
    ::new(t)Dimension(foos);
}

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, DataModel& model, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& model.dimensions & model.geometries ;
}

}
}

void SaveModel(const DataModel& model)
{
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << model;
}

void RestoreModel(DataModel& model)
{
    std::ifstream ofs("filename");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ofs);
    ia >> model;
}

int main()
{
    {
        auto* p0 = new Geometry();
        auto* p1 = new Geometry();

        auto* d2 = new Dimension({ p0, p1 });

        p0->AddDimension(d2);
        p1->AddDimension(d2);

        DataModel model;

        model.geometries.emplace_back(p0);
        model.geometries.emplace_back(p1);
        model.dimensions.emplace_back(d2);

        SaveModel(model);
    }

    DataModel model2;
    RestoreModel(model2);

    return 0;
}
```

The example in main() fails while trying to restore the model with following exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF7F62BA385 in boost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

My guess, while restoring, boost tries to de-serialize the `Dimension` with 2 geometries in `load_construct_data`. Then it tries to de-serialize one of the geometries which again has the `Dimension` as a reference which is of course not constructed currently.

I am new to `boost::serialization`.

My questions are:

- Is serialization of my data model like this feasible?
- Is the general serialization code "correct" (regarding to the interfaces etc.)
- What m I doing wrong on de-serializing the cyclic dependency?

Without the abstract classes it works fine!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Generally boost serialization knows how to deal with cyclic data structures, no special handling is needed.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI thanks for the answer. I am aware that the code snippet is not small. Unfortunately, the problem occurs only when I have these 2 base classes with 2 derived classes. The code is compilable and testable. I would make it smaller if the problem would still occur.

Comment: The problem is not that your code snippet is large, the problem is that it does not reproduce the problem. I cannot copy it, save to a file, compile, run, and see the same problem you see.

Comment: This is an excellent question and the answer isn't at all trivial. Thank you for posting - complete with minimal reproducer, regardless what everyone else seems to think. @n.m.couldbeanAI I didn't have any trouble putting the self-contained example together. The only relevant thing missing was the includes. So that's a lesson for OP: no use to strip 10 lines of includes if that's keeping the example from being self-contained

Comment: @sehe oh that was a big mistake. I had the includes already copied, but I thought having 2 code snippets would be more clear... You are both correct. It was not compilable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyclical references are fine. Your problem appears to be from having virtual base classes.

In particular, commenting the `virtual` keyword here:

```
class Dimension : public /*virtual*/ IDimension {
```

makes the problem go away. My only hunch is that somehow the base-object needs to be constructed before the load-construct-data happens.

Indeed, removing the need for load/save construct data does work even with the virtual base:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a20b4774fb0652a)**

Thinking about it, it makes sense:

- serializing Dimension serializes the related geometries
- the geometries are read back in load-construct-data. Because the object has not been constructed at that time, object tracking cannot have happened yet
- however, deserializing the geometries implies indirectly deserializing their related dimensions, which **requires** correct object tracking to have been complete for the dimensions. Since this is not the case, the wrong branch will be taken and the "effectively corrupt" stream leads the code to invoke Undefined Behaviour

### Summary

Two solutions:

- Drop the (unnecessary?) `virtual` base class modifiers
- Use friend access or intrusive serialization to get the related entities serialized

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code example is very helpful. To your summary. Later I am going to have a diamond-inheritance (unfortunately) with "interfaces". So I need the virtual modifier. I cannot change the classes so I cannot use intrusive serialization

Comment: If you also cannot have `friend`s that means you will have to have intermediate representation for just the (de)serialization and convert as an post-processing step. One thing that might work well is to serialize all entities first and then reconstruct the relations. Let me find a similar solution I made in the past...

Comment: I can't reallt find what I'm looking for. Though this answer/discussion might still be informative: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/215943/2020/6/14